# Java "new File()" does not create file

Tags: java

This will be a really dumb question, but i can't seem to create a new file in java to save my life.

It always throws

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Users/username/Documents/testProject/test.txt (No such file or directory)

I have tried like this:

```
File newFile = new File("Users/username/Documents/testProject/test.txt");
```

and tried this:

```
File newFile = new File("/Users/username/Documents/testProject/test.txt");
```

What am i doing wrong?

Edit: apparently the issue wasn't there. I was trying to read from an empty file later on in the code, sorry folks.

Comment: You are assuming that calling new File() actually creates a file. It doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried newFile.createNewFile() before trying to write anything? And make sure to write down correct path

Comment: What happens when you run a `ls /Users/username/Documents/testProject/test.txt` from the terminal ? Also its not clear what you are trying to do after you create the `File` object.

Comment: `File` constructor does not throw this exception. What are you really doing?

Comment: `new File("...")` only creates a reference to a file path; in order to create a file, you would either write to it, or use `.createNewFile()`

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan it says the directory doesn't exist. If i remove the test.txt i can successfully navigate to it. Edit: i've also tried to to put createNewFile in the next line, it doesn't create it.

Comment: Comming from a python background and learning java..I think this question is perfect..it's just uncomfortable yet easy to grasp the concept until you get use to it...

Comment: I think this question comes from "multiple bad examples" on the internet not showing the magic method that actually creates the file!  :).

Answer (score 14):

`new File("...")` does not create a new file.  It creates a new object (in memory) containing a filename.  You can then perform operations like  `exists()`, `canRead()` and `isDirectory()` on it, and you can invoke `createNewFile()` to create an actual file out of it.

Comment: I did that, and the ide says that createNewFile() is ignored. canRead()  and the like return false.

Comment: The IDE cannot possibly be saying that `createNewFile()` is ignored.  It may be saying that *the result of* `createNewFile()` is ignored.  Which means that you should not ignore the result.

Comment: `canRead()` should return `false` before `createNewFile()` is invoked, and it should return `true` after `createNewFile()` is invoked.  Same for `exists()`.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Mike's answer you will probably need to put double // rather than just a single / as it is used as an escaping sequence. I am not sure if this applies in every situation but in case you still get any errors try this.

Comment: This fixed my problem and I was getting the exact same errors as described above. Thank you